# media queries for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, media-queries

in javascript i have given the cube size....
how to reduce the cube size for iphone screens
is it possible to reduce the cube size using media queries in javascript....
how to make the cube size to 50 for iphone screens

http://jsfiddle.net/XNaYj/

```
Gallery = {
        _config: {
            speed: 500,
            size: 100,
            lightbox: !0,
            closeOnEsc: !0,
            animation: "default",
            slideshow: !1,
            slideshow_speed: 3E3,
            cube_speed: 1E3
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not a great idea to do browser or device sniffing, and feature detection would probably be better, but to answer the question, something like:

```
Gallery = {
    _config: {
        speed: 500,
        size: 100,
        lightbox: !0,
        closeOnEsc: !0,
        animation: "default",
        slideshow: !1,
        slideshow_speed: 3E3,
        cube_speed: 1E3
   }
}

if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) Gallery._config.size = 50;
```

Comment: i have used ur code in the fiddle and tested in iphone but its not working http://jsfiddle.net/AV7vy/

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript equivalent to the following CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width:360px) {
    ...
}
```

is:

```
if( (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) <= 360) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...i used ur code but its not working...i have updated in the fiddle....http://jsfiddle.net/B49Ap/....if sth wrong can u update in the fiddle

Comment: Try narrowing down the code. Also use JSFiddle properly - it provides three panels for a reason!